# django-admin.py startproject opens notepad, instead of creating a project

Tags: windows, django, cmd

Hey, so basically when I try to django-admin.py startproject mysite my notepad with django-admin.py file opens up instead of creating a new actual projects. I'm on windows and just yesterday I created the project and everything was fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your python files would be associated to open with notepad. Change the behaviour to open with IDLE/python.

Answer (score 18):

Instead of `django-admin.py startproject mysite` try `python django-admin.py startproject mysite`

That should work, but...

...you will need to do something more if you want `django-admin.py startproject mysite` to work without adding `python` at the start: -

1. right click any python file ending with the extension .py
2. click on `properties`
3. In the `opens with` section, you should be able to see `notepad`. click on the `change` button next to this.
4. click "browse" and locate your python.exe executable, most probably in c:\pythonxx\ directory then click on "open" then "ok"

That should set you up, or you can always revert back for clarifications.

Answer (score 12):

Another method: Instead of using django-admin.py write django-admin

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

Answer (score 0):

When faced with an issue of django-admin.py opening in an editor

I did this

Select python file and right click and set default open with python console for windows
Problem will be solved automatically